# Выбор элементов из массива в Matlab

Tags: массивы, matlab

Нужно из одного массива создать новый массив, в который будет входить каждый второй элемент из исходного массива. Так как программа стопорится из-за того, что в ней сравниваются массивы разных размерностей (из n элементов и n*2 элементов).
Могу выложить код программы, но не вижу в этом смысла, так как баг в ней уже нашел и описал его выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С кодом вы правы, его не надо выкладывть т.к. он всь под списание - ваша задача на матлабе решается одной строкой `arr2 = arr1(2:2:end);` без всяких циклов, сравнений и иже с ними.

Comment: Ну почему же сразу под списание. Проблема решилась добавлением одной строчки, которую Вы написали. Моя программа решает системы ОДУ методом Рунге и вылетала только из-за того, что в алгоритме сравнивались массивы разных размерностей. Сейчас лишние элементы отбросились и все заработало.
Большое спасибо! :)

Comment: Я имел в виду именно ту часть которая за вытаскивание из массива элементов отвечает. Вы просто так описали проблему что я ее понял ее как ошибка возникала еще на этапе выделения.

А метод Рунге-Кутты по-моему в матлабе есть встроенный с названием ode45 или что-то типа того

Comment: Про ode45 знаю. По заданию нужно написать собственный алгоритм. Результат ode45 берется как эталон